# When you perform a select statement in SQL Server, does the data remain cast in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I write a query like below, does the data in the `WHERE` clause need to be cast again, or does it inherit the cast from the `SELECT` part?

We have a date which is stored as `VARCHAR(25)`, we want to limit the amount of data in the query to 2 months so it doesn’t search through the whole dataset.

Example:

```
DECLARE @StartDate VARCHAR(25) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()), 23), 7);

SELECT 
    CAST([RequestDateTime] AS datetime2) RequestDateTime,  
    [CustomerEmailAddress]
FROM
    table
WHERE
    RequestDateTime > @StartDate
```

The query works, but I want to know if `RequestDateTime` in the `WHERE` clause be the native type in the table, or would it be the cast data type? This is more of an optimisation/curiosity than a problem.

Comment: *If* the column `RequestDateTime` is stored as a `varchar(25)`, which is a seriously design flaw and should be fixed, it won't be cast in the `WHERE`, implicitly or explicitly, as it's being compared to another `varchar(25)`.

Comment: It would not honor the cast you did in the column list of SELECT, it will be whatever type it is in the database. The `<` operator likely does some automatic conversion.

Comment: The `WHERE` is (normally) parsed several steps prior to the `SELECT` as well, so the fact that you are casting it in the `SELECT` will have no bearing on the `WHERE` (of course, the same might not true if you are using a derived table, such as a CTE, and then using the `WHERE` against that).

Comment: The `WHERE` cannot refer to a column in the `SELECT`, so it necessarily refers to the column in the table. The result is the same as if you had written `CAST([RequestDateTime] AS datetime2) AS Coconut`.

Comment: Also if you are using `CAST` to `varchar` in order to return a date without a time, consider casting to `date` instead. And for months, use `EOMONTH()`

Comment: For any comparison, the expressions must be of the same datatype before they can be compared. If they have different datatypes, then a conversion occurs in the database engine based on [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). In your case, your column and variable are varchar so there is no conversion. Implicit conversion is supported for most - but not all - datatype combinations.